Proof of sufficient fund for France visa
I am an Indian student who will be attending the global summer school program offered by HEC Paris this July. While applying for the visa, I came across a "Proof of sufficient funds" document, which is needed to get the visa.
My brother will sponsoring my trip, so I understand that I'll have to submit his account statement, income tax returns etc. But the thing is my brother left his high-paying job recently to focus more on his startup. Because of that, his cashflow for the past year is not so great (60k a month maybe) and he also doesn't have much balance left in the account (around 200,000 Rs as of now). But he has a good amount of money in his PF and mutual funds.
So during the visa application process, can I show his PF and mutual funds as proof of sufficient funds or should he transfer some funds to his savings account?

What duration is the summer school and what accommodation is included? 2lakhs = around 2,200€,  the general requirement for financial means to obtain a visa for France is to have at least €65 per day, less if you’re staying with a family member/friend, while if you have no accommodation at all a minimum of €120 per day is required to be at your disposal during your stay.

The duration of stay in Schengen area is 23 days, the program fee of 3200 euros and accommodation fee of 480 euros is already paid for.

You could use your brothers PF and Mutual Funds statements just that ask your brother to provide in writing that he is there to support you in any circumstances. Schengen visa providers really focus on various other factors too such as you have paid the fees for the program and accommodation and your purpose don’t forget to show ties to your home country like demonstrate you’d be back on time when you visa expires because you are a student and need to attend your classes

No idea about how France and/or schengen countries look at the source of funds. But for a lot of countries, your brothers finances are immaterial, his promise to support you isn't worth the piece of paper it's written on as there is no legal obligation for him to do so.
I think you should focus on your application, it's not uncommon for students to be young and not have money. Ask your school if they have any guidance on this, proof of having paid tuition is probably more useful and relevant.

Since the summer school fee and accommodation are the major portion of the trip costs (excluding the flight, which for Schengen typically needs to be bought in advance of applying anyway), and in a comment you mention they are already paid for, your ‘shortfall’ is presumably just day-to-day personal expenses. That likely isn’t a huge sum out of the ‘good amount of money in his PF and Mutual fund’ you say he has. If I were in your shoes I would have your brother transfer the money to your account thereby avoiding any doubt that the funds are actually available to you, not just promised to you.
Unless I’m mistaken I believe Schengen doesn’t put quite the same emphasis on provenance of funds / ‘funds parking’ as say the UK does. However, have your brother provide the paperwork proving where the money came from.

PF’s , Mutual Funds and other form of investment like that which can  be easily liquidated, ’meaning in case when needed it can be converted into cash. As you have mentioned you are a student then you are dependent on someone else like your brother in this case. Your brother should now provide document showing ties and supporting evidence that he will support you while you are on the travel attending this program.
There is no hard and fast rule of money transfer into your or his account (this could raise suspicions) as long your purpose is clear which is to attend the program and your brother is supporting you , you could provide his bank statements and as well as Mutual Fund documents it would be ideal if he could show on paper that he is lending you money equivalent to the amount of days your are staying in France.
You could also add documents why this program is important for your career demonstrating that if you do this what potential opportunities you’d have in future so detail this out as much possible like sharing your past experiences too.
I have had a friend when he was a student saved 1000 euros and travelled to Germany in 2019 by  simply crafting a truthful cover letter without any extra support or additional savings at disposal.
So , make sure you demonstrate all the necessary information in your cover letter too but don’t forget to attach the documents as required by the VFS and embassy
